# Given that $f(x^2 - x) + xg(x^3 - x) = (x^2 - 4)h(x), \forall x \in \mathbb R$. Calculate the minimum value of $[f(0)]^2 + 8[g(3)]^2$.

Tags: functions, polynomials

> $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ are real, non-constant polynomials such that the total of the degrees of $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ does not succeed $5$ and the coefficient of the monomial with the highest degree of $h(x)$ is $1$.
>
> Given that $$\large f(x^2 - x) + xg(x^3 - x) = (x^2 - 4)h(x), \forall x \in \mathbb R$$. Calculate the minimum value of $$\large [f(0)]^2 + 8[g(3)]^2$$

There's a provided solution below by me. Please tell me whether there are any broken or weak bonds between claims. I will get to fixing it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I know, we have that $\left\{ \begin{align} \deg f(x) &\le 2\\ \deg g(x) &= 1\\ \deg h(x) &= 2 \end{align} \right.$

Let $g(x) = mx + p$ and $h(x) = x^2 + nx + q$ $(m, p, n, q \in \mathbb R$ and $m \ne 0)$

(because the coefficient of the monomial with the highest degree of $h(x)$ is $1$).

We have that $f(x^2 - x) = (x^2 - 4)h(x) - xg(x^3 - x)$

$ = (x^2 - 4)(x^2 + nx + q) - x[m(x^3 - x) + p]$

$ = (1 - m)x^4 + nx^3 + (m + q - 4)x^2 - (p + 4n)x - 4q, \forall x \in \mathbb R$

Since $\deg f(x) \le 2, \forall x \in \mathbb R \implies 1 - m = n = 0$

$\implies g(x) = x + p, h(x) = x^2 + q$ and $f(x) = (q - 3)x^2 - px - 4q$.

We have that $[f(0)]^2 + 8[g(3)]^2 = [(q - 3) \cdot 0^2 - p \cdot 0 - 4q]^2 + 8(3 + p)^2$

$ = 8(p + 3)^2 + 16q^2 \ge 0 \iff (p, q) = (-3, 0)$